# Playlist scroller mp3 player

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on a music player and I have a working playlist, but I need the playlist to be short so that if a lot of songs are added it doesn't go off-screen.
To do that I created a mask and a scrollbar.
The song names are in the playlist, and new ones can be added at any given time.

```
function startDragging2(MouseEvent)
    {
        Playlistslider.playlistSliderHandle.startDrag(false,rectangle2);
        dragging = true;
    }

    function stopDragging2(MouseEvent)
    {
        if(dragging)
        {
            dragging = false;
            Playlistslider.playlistSliderHandle.stopDrag();
        }
    }

    function adjustY(Event)
    {
        var myY:Number = Playlistslider.playlistSliderHandle.y;
        CollectionMC.y = (myY * -CollectionMC.numChildren);  <--------
    }
```

Now what I want to do is make it so that the scrollbar handle determines the position of the parent movieclip that contains the song names.
If I scroll down, I want it to go no further than the amount of songs that are in the list.
Right now it scrolls, but not enough so not the whole list shows.

What I need is a simple formula that decides the y position of the parent movieclip relative to the y position of the slider handle.

Thanks in advance,

Milan.

EDIT: I forgot to add, the first name is at Y:20. Second at Y:40. Third at Y:60, and so forth

EDIT 2:
With this formula I'm close, but I can always scroll a space of 6 names (120 Y) too far.

```
var myY:Number = Playlistslider.playlistSliderHandle.y;
CollectionMC.y = -(myY * (CollectionMC.numChildren / 6));
```

EDIT 3: I have changed the height of the mask and the scrollbar to 100 to make it easier.
Now 5 names can show inside the mask.
When I add 5 songs the scrollbar appears, but it's not supposed to scroll down when I use it because all songs fit inside the mask.
But when I add another one I want it to scroll down enough to show the 6th name and not see the first name. But instead it scrolls the size of the mask(100) further down than it's supposed to, no matter how many songs I add.

EDIT 4: I have found the solution. The right formula is this:

```
CollectionMC.y = (((CollectionMC.numChildren - 5) * -0.2) * myY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use fl's or flex's scrollbar? I know some people hate me for suggesting it, but what he wants to do is simple enough to ignore the...unpleasantness. You can even skin it the way you like it!

Comment: Sorry I'm purely looking for a formula.

Comment: @user2281425 Here you go :D http://www.feizsite.com/Sothink/Sothink_SWF_Easy/scrollbar/index.html Don't forget to pick my answer so others get it in the search.

Comment: When I download the source it only has .gla files. I have no idea what they are and changing them to .fla makes them unusable.

Comment: @user2281425 Sorry dude, I thought that person put the right thing. I found this tutorial tho. If its not satisfactory, search Kirupa's website for it, Senocular has most likely posted about it. Cheers. http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?245468-Scrollbars-amp-Code-structure-Actionscript-3-0